# why function does not work to get display image on label tkinter python, but it works not using function

Tags: python, image, tkinter

This code without function does work to get display image on label tkinter python 3.8.5.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    import os
    import os.path

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Test_image")
    root.geometry("1000x600")

    # def display_image():
    images_folder = "C:/TextSoundSource/B-V/I-WORD-E-00-B-V-0-renamed"
    os.chdir(images_folder)
    displaying_img = "022.jpg"

    # Open Image
    img = Image.open(displaying_img)

    # Resize Image
    resized = img.resize((300, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    resized_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)

    image_display_frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Image", font=(
         "times", 15, "bold"), bg="Navyblue", fg="white", bd=5)
    image_display_frame.place(x=0, y=0, width=1000, height=300)

    img_label = Label(image_display_frame, image=resized_img)

    img_label.pack(pady=20)

    # display_image()
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: getting image works]

But when using function like below it does not work, how do I get images by using function?

```
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    import os
    import os.path

    # == == == == == == == == == == == ======== 
    # Using function does not work ???? why ???
    # == == == == == == == == == == == ========

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Test_image")
    root.geometry("1000x600")

    def display_image():
        images_folder = "C:/TextSoundSource/B-V/I-WORD-E-00-B-V-0-renamed"
        os.chdir(images_folder)
        displaying_img = "001.jpg"

        # Open Image
        img = Image.open(displaying_img)

        # Resize Image
        resized = img.resize((300, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        resized_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)

        image_display_frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Image", font=(
            "times", 15, "bold"), bg="Navyblue", fg="white", bd=5)
        image_display_frame.place(x=0, y=0, width=1000, height=300)

        img_label = Label(image_display_frame, image=resized_img)
        img_label.pack(pady=20)

    display_image()
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: Using function does not work to get image display, why?]

I appreciate in advance, please let me know how to get image display by using function in tkinter python.

Comment: Add `global resized_img` inside the function or just `root.anything = resized_img`.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, a function has its own local scope for object names. When you exit the function all names are garbage collected and not available for the program.

You can add the image reference to the global scope with the `global` keyword, as @Cool cloud suggests. Another common technique is to save the image reference to the label widget:

```
img_label.image = resized_img
```

Comment: It was such a useful key answer to me. It works.